# OpenCart language issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

I am working with opencart for the first time. It's not difficult, but how do I adjust language for mobile version? Desktop version has a dropdown, but for mobile version I need the default list. 
I added this to my `language.tpl` , but it outputs both mobile and desktop version.
Should I create new `.tpl` file for this?

```html
<div class="show-mobile hidden-lg hidden-md clearfix">  
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="language"><?php echo $text_language; ?><br />
    <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
    <img src="image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', '<?php echo $language['code']; ?>'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="language_code" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" />
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, ask only one question at a time (I mean the same topic). The part with images should be asked as a separate question and including the code that is causing you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was ok,
try using the css disable either one.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) { /* desktop version */
    #defaultList{
        display: none;
    }

    #dropDownList{
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { /* mobileversion */
    #defaultList{
        display: block;
    }

    #dropDownList{
        display: none;
    }
}
```